# Html agility pack in Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, windows-8, rss, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to create a football Windows 8 Application in c#. 
In my hub page I would like to show the fixtures of the Barclays Premier League.
Now I'm wondering if I can get the data from this website : http://espnfc.com/fixtures/_/league/eng.1/english-premier-league?cc=5739

Is this possible with the Html Agility pack? Or does anyone know some great RSS feeds?
Feel free to share your thoughts about other options!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind you would a WinRT compiled version of the HTML Agility Pack for it to work as a Windows Store application library.

Parsing web-pages for that kind of data is definitely possible, I found it easy using Xpath. There's a lot of extensions for browsers that will help you construct queries, for example i[Xpath Helper for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl).

Here's a sample of the code I developed to get dates of matches: need to construct to get dates of matches from a fixtures website:

```
var url = "http://www.livefootball.com/football/england/premier-league/results/all/";
var webGet = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
var document = webGet.Load(url);
var dates = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//dl[@class='mElHeaderDet']");
foreach (var node in dates)
        {
            listOfDates.Add(node.InnerText);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks great! What do you exactly mean with the WinRT compiled version of the nu-get package?
Also when I try the code I get an error on webGet.Load(url) saying 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb' does not contain a definition for 'Load' and no extension method 'Load' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Which is strange because I've added the reference.

Comment: I'm sorry, after some reading it seems that Xpath is not supported in Windows 8 version of HTML Agility Pack. You could just download the html document, convert it to xml and use SgmlReader, but I don't have any code snippets at the moment. I'll try to come up with something later.